# How can I set an ECS cluster status to ACTIVE

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-ecs, ec2-ami

I've deleted the default cluster with aws console management and now I want to set it to ACTIVE on my EC2 instance.

Below the output of 
`aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster default`

> {
>       "clusters": [
>           {
>               "status": "INACTIVE", 
>               "statistics": [], 
>               "tags": [], 
>               "clusterName": "default", 
>               "registeredContainerInstancesCount": 0, 
>               "pendingTasksCount": 0, 
>               "runningTasksCount": 0, 
>               "activeServicesCount": 0, 
>               "clusterArn": "******************/default"
>           }
>       ], 
>       "failures": []
>   }

How can I do that.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create and make it ACTIVE

> aws ecs create-cluster --cluster default

you can verify again by running:

> aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster default